# Can't visit one site on my network, but can view it on a different network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, cache

Trying to figure out why I can't view a certain site on my wi-fi network, but I can view it on my mobile device (different network). I have cleared out my browser caches, flushed the DNS cache on each browser, and flushed the DNS cache on my mac. Still no luck.

Also tried to use public DNS (Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) and got the same results as below, depending on which network I use.

Why can't I view the site on my main network? I could access it before but not for the last week or so.

Here's what I see when I dig on my wi-fi network (xfinity):

```
$foo dig mysite.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mysite.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 9791
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 58 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:558:feed::1#53(2001:558:feed::1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 13 22:32:05 EST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

When I dig the same site using my mobile device (AT&T):

```
foo$ dig mysite.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mysite.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26560
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mysite.com      1117    IN  A   162.159.134.42

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 172.20.10.1#53(172.20.10.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 13 22:37:19 EST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: Does your domain pass the tests at https://dnsviz.net?

Comment: Parental screening?

Comment: @user1686 - Yes it did, and I checked it against another domain that I can reach and it had the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This js a DNS problem.

I comment that your first lookup appears to ve trying to reach IPV6 nameservers and did not get an answer  while your second was a straight IPV4 query.  I expect disabling IPV6 cluld solve your problem.

If "mysite.com" is the domain associated with your local network that could compound your issues as well.

Comment: It did get an answer. The dig output (the SERVFAIL error code) says that the *DNS server* failed to obtain the data – this isn't going to change depending on how the OS contacts that server.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of a “[black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_(networking))” attack.

If you configure the router in such a way that when your device asks the router where to look for this website, the router simply doesn't know because the router tables modified only for your mac address.

You could test whether this is the case by changing your mac address to something else.